# Using function for default value of parameter in constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop, constructor, php-5.4

A workaround was described here: [PHP function as parameter default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740687/php-function-as-parameter-default)

But I was wondering why this doesn't work:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
function __construct($paramsIn=array("timestamp"=>time()-7200,"api-key"=>"blah"),                       
                         $urlIn="http://www.example.com/rest")
{ //...etcetc
}
```

I get the error:

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in **filename.php**

It's specifically related to the time() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for function arguments only supports literals, that is strings, numbers, booleans, null and arrays. Function calls like `time()` are not supported. The reason for this is that the function signature should describe the interface and be independent of runtime values. The same applies to initializing object properties in a class.

As your link points out, the workaround is to use `null` and process it within the function body.

```
function __construct($paramsIn=array("timestamp"=> null,"api-key"=>"blah"),                       
                         $urlIn="http://www.example.com/rest")
{
    if(!isset($paramsIn['timestamp']) || is_null($paramsIn['timestamp'])){
        $paramsIn['timestamp'] = time() - 7200;
    }

    // this is now the equivalent of having time() as a default value
}
```